# How to know fps of game running on Mesa3D Windows 10

Tags: game-development, opengl

I am running some old OpenGL 3D application. I don´t have source code from the application but I assume it was implemented with OpenGL 2.0 or 2.1. I am running it on Windows 10 on Intel UHD graphics 630 and doing some comparison using standard Windows/Intel OpenGL drivers vs. Mesa3D and need to know FPS.

When the application is launched using standard Win/Intel drivers I can use Fraps tool or Microsoft Game Bar (Win + G buttons) to see FPS. But when I launch the application using Mesa3D (using libglapi.dll, opengl32.dll, dxil.dll, libgallium_wgl.dll) no application is possible to display the FPS.

Obviously most of the tools acquire FPS from standard drivers and using Mesa3D those drivers are not used so not possible to display FPS.

- Is there some way or some tool to get know FPS on Mesa on Windows?
- Something like Gallium HUD for Linux?